# Is it possible to forward request to another host in nginx?

Tags: nginx, forward

Some service calls my server with JSON data:
`POST http://example.com/controller/method`

I need to send same JSON data to another host on my VPS:
`POST http://staging.example.com/controller/method`

Now I'm using CURL to send request from production to staging. I think it is bad idea, but works.

So, is it possible to configure nginx that it will forward specific requests to another site?

Comment: why not, have you tried [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)?

Comment: @Anatoly sites configurations are separated into files. Also, all these requests are already proxy_passed to Symfony application as php5-fpm.